# Show product price in custom block

Tags: magento-2.1, module, price, product-prices

I am developing a custom module with a custom block which displays a list of products.

My Block class:

```
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Products extends Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getHomeProducts()
    {

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(6);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

.phtml file:

```
<?php
$productCollection = $block->getHomeProducts();
?>
<?php if($productCollection->count() > 0) : ?>
    <div class="lrnt_hp_products">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($productCollection as $product) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog') . 'product' . $product->getImage(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></a></h2>
                    // here I would like to print the price
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am trying to show product price in the phtml file but could not find proper way to show the price.

I now I can print it with:

> $product->getPrice()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue()

and searching which automatically prints the `final_price`, the `special-price` if these are present etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: $product->getFinalPrice() prints only the discounted price, I would like to print both the regular and the discounted price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch the Product price in custom module same as listing page using price render block. Add the below function in your custom block class.

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @return string
 */
public function getProductPrice($product)
{
    $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default')
        ->setData('is_product_list', true);

    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'include_container' => true,
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                'list_category_page' => true
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

and Call the function in template like below and pass Product Object as argument:

```
<?php echo $block->getProductPrice($product); ?>
```